# Logging events with Firebase

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, google-analytics

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that supports Android and iOS. I am trying to implement Google Analytics GA4. I followed this manual: https://thewissen.io/using-firebase-analytics-in-your-xamarin-forms-app/.

Now everything seems to be in place, and I should be ready to log events, as it is described in the manual:

```
IFirebaseAnalyticsService service = DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAnalyticsService>();
service?.LogEvent("MyEventHere");
```

Or with the parameters:

```
service?.LogEvent(event, name, value);
```

Specifically, I need to log screen views (including screen name), button presses (including name of the functionality, e.g. Print etc), and errors (including fatal or not, and the message).

I cannot figure out though what the **event** and **name** can be. I assume, these values should not be just anything, but belong to a specific set. E.g. I found https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews examples for logging screen views. But those examples include Swift, Objective-C and some others, but not C#.

How can I do it in my Xamarin.Forms C# code? Or maybe I am wrong, and I can pass anything as event and as parameter?

Comment: they are just strings, you can use any values you want.  If you look at the Dart example for "Manually Track Screens" you'll see that they appear to be using some standardized tags for that tracking.

Comment: @Jason But isn't screen_view a standard pre-set event id?

Comment: Yes, as I just noted they appear to use some standardized tags for that function.  Most event tracking systems I've worked with are pretty open ended.  This seems like something that you should just try and see how it works for your needs.

Comment: @Jason I made some tests, and need to wait until tomorrow, when the results would show up... I will let you know. Thank you!

Comment: @Jason That works. It would not accept pre-defined event ids like app_exception, as those are logged automatically. So I use my custom event names. If you make your first comment an answer, I will mark it.